# SQL connectivity to Progress DB?

Tags: sql, openedge, progress-db

> We are trying to connect with progressdb through php.When i execute the below
>         command its not giving the sql connect screen.
>
> isql -v qhn sysprogress sysprogress
>
> its trying to connect with different ports like 1027,2018 and goes on.
>   But we started the database on port 5555.
>
> Here is the log file

```
 2014/09/22@11:48:40.338-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) SQL Server 11.3.01 
 started, configuration: "qhn.virtualconfig" 
 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) "qhn" started on     
 IPv4 port 1028 for address 0.0.0.0, pid 5837 (0x000016cd).
 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) Thread stack size: 
 1024000 (bytes).

[2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) DLC from 
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE is: /u/psc113f 


 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) WRKDIR from 
 ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE is: /usr/wrk/ 

 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) JDKHOME from 
  DEFAULT is:  
 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) JREHOME from 
 ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE is: [[java-home]] 

 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----) CLASSPATH from 
 DEFAULT is: 

 [2014/09/22@11:48:40.341-0400] P-5837       T-1073785728 I SQLSRV2 1: (-----)   
 PROSQL_LOCKWAIT_TIMEOUT value is: 5 seconds
```

> why its not establishing the connection to progress db?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Where is the PHP angle?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: it doen't show any error message.it shows balnk screen after executing the isql command

Comment: How is the DSN defined?

Comment: if ($conn_id=odbc_connect("qhn","sysprogress","sysprogress", SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC )){
if we connect using php its giving error unable to connect to DSN in db.php on line 11( which is the above line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log file extract seems to show a SQL borker starting at:

```
"qhn" started on IPv4 port 1028 for address 0.0.0.0
```

Rather that 5555 and localhost.

You should probably verify that SQL connectivity is setup correctly using the Progress supplied sqlexp tool first.

From a PROENV window the following should work assuming that the "sysprogress" user has a password of "sysprogress" and that the SQL broker is started on port 1028 etc (as the info above seems to show):

```
sqlexp -user sysprogress -password sysprogress -db dbName -H 0.0.0.0 -S 1028
```

(although i suspect that 0.0.0.0 is probably bogus...)

Comment: we get the following error after executing sqlexp.     root@mtceqdl001 qhndbs]# sqlexp
OpenEdge Release 11.3 as of Wed Jul 17 16:45:17 EDT 2013
Progress sqlexp Messages:

Java Virtual Machine could not be found.

JREHOME environment variable may not be set correctly.
Set JREHOME variable to a valid directory.

JREHOME setting: [[java-home]]

Comment: could you please tell me how to set JREHOME and valid directory to set.when i do java -version its giving                      OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (rhel-4.1.13.1.el5_10-i386)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
when i do echo $JREHOME its giving nothing

Comment: The easy way to do it is to use the "proenv" shell.  It should be set in there.  Otherwise you need to set the variable yourself and the value depends on where Java is installed.  On my Linux system JAVAHOME, JREHOME and JAVA_ROOT are all set to /usr/lib64/jvm/jre

Comment: _sqlsrv2 started on port 1027 while connecting through isql from remote machine to database server.Is it recommended to open port 1027 from firewall?

Comment: If you want to access it from the other side of the firewall then, of course, the port needs to be open.  But you really ought to first establish that it is setup correctly on localhost.  Stackoverflow really isn't a discussion forum.  You ought to try PEG, Progress Communities or ProgressTalk for a long and involved problem solving back and forth Q&A.

Comment: we are able to connect the db through php.we started the database with maxport and minport as 6666.so the _sqlsrv2 connects to these ports.Thanks for your help.